# Owl-Carousel Vs VueJS

Tags: vue.js, owl-carousel

Estou trabalhando a pouco tempo com o VueJS e recentemente peguei um template para incorporar na minha aplicação e ele possui um slide o qual utiliza o plugin Owl-Carousel, portanto de forma alguma to conseguindo utilizar esse plugin.

**Qual a situação:** Na primeira instância quando abro a página pela primeira vez tudo é carregado corretamente, portanto ao clicar em uma outra aba e depois voltar pra aba home ai já não funciona mais, é como se o Vue Router não conseguisse carregar as funcionalidades dessa dependência! Dai quando retiro a class `Owl-carousel` da `Div`volta a funcionar normalmente com o slide desconfigurado... é como se o VueJS não tivesse aceitando esse plugin!

> Lembrando que essas dependências estão de forma estáticas dentro da pasta public

Meu component onde esta o slide:

```
    <template>
  <div class="hello">
      <section class="hero-area">
   <div class="hero-slides owl-carousel">

            <!-- Single Hero Slide -->
            <div class="single-hero-slide d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <!-- Slide Img -->
                <div class="slide-img bg-img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/bg-1.png);"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-9">
                            <!-- Slide Content -->
                            <div class="hero-slides-content" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="100ms">
                                <div class="line" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="300ms"></div>
                                <h2 data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="500ms">Pousada Vila de Atalaia</h2>
                                <p data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                    adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada lorem maximus mauris sceleri sque, at rutrum nulla
                                    dictum. Ut ac ligula sapien. Suspendisse cursus faucibus finibus.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Single Hero Slide -->
            <div class="single-hero-slide d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <!-- Slide Img -->
                <div class="slide-img bg-img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/bg-2.png);"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-9">
                            <!-- Slide Content -->
                            <div class="hero-slides-content" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="100ms">
                                <div class="line" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="300ms"></div>
                                <h2 data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="500ms">Canavieiras - Bahia</h2>
                                <p data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                    adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada lorem maximus mauris sceleri sque, at rutrum nulla
                                    dictum. Ut ac ligula sapien. Suspendisse cursus faucibus finibus.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn palatin-btn mt-50" data-animation="fadeInUp"
                                    data-delay="900ms">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Single Hero Slide -->
            <div class="single-hero-slide d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <!-- Slide Img -->
                <div class="slide-img bg-img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/bg-3.png);"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-9">
                            <!-- Slide Content -->
                            <div class="hero-slides-content" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="100ms">
                                <div class="line" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="300ms"></div>
                                <h2 data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="500ms">Enjoy your life</h2>
                                <p data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                    adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada lorem maximus mauris sceleri sque, at rutrum nulla
                                    dictum. Ut ac ligula sapien. Suspendisse cursus faucibus finibus.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn palatin-btn mt-50" data-animation="fadeInUp"
                                    data-delay="900ms">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

  </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data(){
    return{
      publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

***Alguém teria alguma ideia do que possa está acontecendo e poderia me dar algumas ideias de como solucionar isso?***

Comment: Não tem relação com o problema, mas fica um alerta que o autor do owl-carousel diz que o plugin está praticamente morto e sugere que utilizem o [tiny-slider](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2#yeah-so-this-is-pretty-much-dead-do-yourself-a-favor-and-switch-to-tiny-slider).

Comment: @RenanGomes bom saber disso! Estou vendo uma maneira de fazer esse efeito! Obrigado pela informação!!